# With gcc linkers and C, is there any way of triggering a linker error if a pointer finally evaluates to NULL?

Tags: c, gcc, null, linker, non-nullable

At first, I tried using __attribute__ ((__nonnull__)) to do this, but this only triggers a gcc compiler warning when the parameter expression was immediately NULL. The problem for me is that if the parameter expression instead **subsequently** evaluates to NULL inside the linker (e.g. if it was indirected via a const pointer dereference), this nonnull test doesn't appear to get triggered.

So, is there any way of triggering some kind of gcc *linker* error when an expression *finally* evaluates to 0 inside the linker? I would like to use this as a kind of really late static assert, because nonnull doesn't seem late enough to be genuinely safe.

Note: I'm only looking for a gcc-specific linker trick for this at the moment, I'm not interested in other compilers/linkers. Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean "evaluate" in the context of linker? How or where does linker "evaluate" an expression? Inside the linking script? `this nonnull test doesn't appear to get triggered.` Please post code example. I do not understand.  `when an expression finally evaluates to 0 inside the linker` When does an expression "finally" evaluates to 0 inside the linker? How can it evaluate to something different in linker and during compilation?

Comment: It is not possible. Linker does not check any memory locations for any values. It is not a linker task. Do it runtime

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way of triggering a linker error if a pointer finally evaluates to NULL?

Assuming that you mean: is there a way to make a program fail to build (at compile or link time) if the program might at *execution time* try to dereference a `NULL` pointer, the answer is no.

Detecting whether a program may dereference a `NULL` pointer is equivalent to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), which is known to be *undecidable*.